# matplotlib: override underscore in string when using LaTeX in text box

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I need to write in the text box of a plot, and within a LaTeX environment (since I also need to write some math code), the name of a variable that contains an underscore.

The problem is that LaTeX interprets the underscore in the variable's name as a subindex command, and the name of the variable is distorted. See (MWE below):

[image]

where the name of the variable is `m_out`.

How can I write a string containing an underscore without LaTeX interpreting it as the subindex command?

In pure LaTeX I could use the `\textunderscore` command to write:

```
N = m \textunderscore out \pm 0.2
```

which correctly produces:

[image]

but this doesn't seem to work here.

---

**MWE**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.offsetbox as offsetbox
import random

# Generate random data.
x = [random.random() for i in xrange(10)]
y = [random.random() for i in xrange(10)]

# Define string with underscore.
name = 'm_out'

# Create plot.
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot()

# Add text box
text = r'$N={}\pm0.2$'.format(name)
ob = offsetbox.AnchoredText(text, loc=1, prop=dict(size=12))
ax.add_artist(ob)
plt.scatter(x, y)

# Save plot to file.
fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('out.png')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple escape does the trick:

```
name = 'm\_out'
```

[image: matplotlib-generated image]

Comment: Very simple indeed, should've thought of that. Thank you!